# WPFにおけるストリングの数え方

Tags: c#, wpf

イベント(Btn_Click)で、文字の中に対象の言葉や文字などを数えるには？
下記のような方法をよく見かけるのですが、static int となっているためか、ボタンとの連動はできるのでしょうか。

```
static int countOccurences(string str, string word) 
{ 
    // split the string by spaces 
    string[] a = str.Split(' '); 

    // search for pattern in string 
    int count = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
    { 
        // if match found increase count 
        if (word.Equals(a[i])) 
            count++; 
    } 

    return count; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

気にされている static については、このメソッドがインスタンスによらずに使えるという意味であり、Button_Click からの利用には問題ありません。
ただし、このコードは半角スペース区切りで単語が存在し、その中から一致する単語を数えるコードなので、日本語文章における文字・文字列を探すことには使えないと思われます。

Comment: アルファベットで作ろうとしています。stringなのかcharなのかも迷うところです。